# Xcode Fonts: How to know if I need to purchase a license?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, licensing

I would like to use the `Avenir Next` font in my iOS app. 
I see in Fonts.com that this font cost money. But I also see that it is built-in to Xcode. 
So the question - do I still need to purchase a liscence if I want to use it in a commercial app?

Answer (score 1):

So I have the answer: as long as the Binary of the font was not manually added - and in my case, there is no need for that, as it included in the OS (since iOS 6) - no liscence is needed

Comment: Where did you find this answer?